# Explicit range beween values

Tags: text-processing

Is there any clean way of calculating the range between elements of the second column of a text file using some bash magic? (I'm currently doing this using Python).

Input: File 1

```
A   1-5
A   17-19
B   1-5
B   4-6
```

Expected output: File 2

```
A   1,2,3,4,5,17,18,19
B   1,2,3,4,5,6
```

*EDIT* @Anthon: to cumulate elements I'm using something like this (then calculate the ranges using a for loop)

```
d_pos= {} 
for row in open('File.txt'): 
    x, y = [ value.strip() for value in row.split('\t')] 
    if x in d_pos:        
        d_pos[x].append(y)    
    else:        
        d_pos[x] = [y]
```

Comment: I would argue that using Python **is** the clean way. Are you using a dict of sets to accumulate the elements?

Comment: Please refer to my above edited question for the cumulation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight bash, since you asked (though note I'm using associative arrays, requiring bash 4.0).

The trick is in the *brace sequence expansion* expression `{x..y}` which, for integers x any y expands to the inclusive range of values (i.e. [x,y]) as a textual list. We need to throw in an `eval` too, since brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

```
declare -A data seen  # explicit associative arrays
while read col range; do
   data[$col]="${data[$col]} $(eval echo {${range/-/..}})"
done <<DATA
A   1-5
A   17-19
B   1-5
B   4-6
DATA

# dump array
#declare -p data

for ii in ${!data[@]}; do
    seen=();  datum=""
    # build list of unique values
    for dd in ${data[$ii]}; do
        (( ${seen[$dd]:-0} )) || datum="$datum $dd"
        let seen[$dd]++
    done

    datum=${datum# }     # drop leading space
    datum=${datum// /,}  # spaces to commas
    printf "%-4s %s\n" "$ii" "$datum"
done
```

A variation on the sequence expansion is `a{x..y}b` where "a" is prepended and "b" is appended to each term of the expansion: you can use this to append a "," and alter the datum variable fiddling if desired. Sequence expansion handles increments of 1, or -1 if x > y

You may also need to sort the output: iterating the keys of an associative array has no well-defined order, and you haven't stated if the input ranges are pre-sorted (so I didn't over-complicate the code).

Comment: oops, not quite right yet, I need to fix overlap...

Comment: updated to output unique values only.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -anle '
    ($s,$e) = split "-", $F[1];
    push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $s..$e; 
    END {
        $" = ",";
        print "$_   @{[uniq@{$h{$_}}]}" for keys %h;
    }
' file
A   1,2,3,4,5,17,18,19
B   1,2,3,4,5,6
```

If you don't want to use `List::MoreUtils`, since when it's not in core, you can do:

```
$ perl -anle '
    ($s,$e) = split "-", $F[1];
    push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $s..$e; 
    END {
        $" = ",";
        for $k (keys %h) {
            %u=();
            print "$k   @{[grep {!$u{$_}++} @{$h{$k}}]}";
        }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code comes close, but e.g. cannot deal with the overlap of 4 and 5 for item B.

The following handles that correctly using a `set()` to prevent the overlap, setdefault to eliminate the explicit test it the key already exists in `d_pos` and `.split()` on the input line to be less dependent on the `\t` character and eliminating the explicit `.strip()`:

```
d_pos= {}
for row in open('File.txt'):
    x, y = [ value for value in row.split()]
    y1, y2 = map(int, y.split('-'))
    d_pos.setdefault(x, set()).update(range (y1, y2+1))
for x in sorted(d_pos):
    print '{}\t{}'.format(x, ','.join(map(str, d_pos[x])))
```

Comment: @Dovah Your welcome, please be aware that this starts to come close to a generic programming question that would be more appropriate on [so]