# Calculate intervals

Tags: awk

How to explicit the intervals between numerical values in a file? (better if an awk one-liner)

Input:

```
A    1-3
B    5-7
```

Output

```
A    1,2,3
B    5,6,7
```

Code I've tried so far:

```
sed -i 's/-/\t/g' input #splits the digits to separated columns

awk '{print$1"\t"$3-$2+1}' input > output #prints key and interval width
```

But, thid only allows computing the number of values within the interval. For example, the output will look like:

```
A    3
B    3
```

Comment: you want to compute the intermediate values, is that it?

Comment: `sed 's/-/\t/g'` ;  `awk '{print$1"\t"$3-$2+1}' input > output` is only computing the number of values within the interval. For example, for A it will look like: `A    3` but I'd like it to explicit its composants like: `A    1,2,3`

Comment: @Dovah: How about this:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144769/explicit-range-beween-values/144770#144770? It's similar with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do this by taking advantage of the shell's brace expansion:

```
$ while read a b; do echo $a $(eval echo {"$(sed 's/-/../' <<<$b)"}); done < file
A 1 2 3
B 5 6 7
```

or, to have comma separated values

```
$ while read a b; do 
    echo $a $(eval echo {"$(sed 's/-/../' <<<$b)"} | sed 's/ /,/g'); 
  done < file
A 1,2,3
B 5,6,7
```

Since you asked for an awk one liner, you could try:

```
$ sed 's/-/ /' file | 
    awk '{printf "%s ", $1; for(i=$2;i<=$NF-1;i++){printf "%d,", i}; print $NF}' 
A 1,2,3
B 5,6,7
```

or, to do the whole thing in awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/-/," ")}{printf "%s ", $1; 
                       for(i=$2;i<=$NF-1;i++){printf "%d,", i}; print $NF}' file
A 1,2,3
B 5,6,7
```

Comment: possibly an even more bashed-up variant: `while read a b ; do vals=( $(eval echo "{${b/-/..}}") ) ; (IFS=, ; printf '%s\t%s\n' "$a" "${vals[*]}"); done < file`

Comment: @steeldriver ah, yes, clever use of IFS.